# Appmenu has disappeared after panel restore

Tags: gnome-panel, appmenu

After getting past this hurdle: [gnome-panel will not start after running purge command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14706/gnome-panel-will-not-start-after-running-purge-command) i seem to ave lost appmenu. All of the packages related to it have been installed, however it does not show up in the 'add to panel' menu. Do i need to enable something else in order to see it?

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed ubuntu desktop?If not install it first `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you a default set of panels:

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restating the panel,

`killall gnome-panel`

If the above command din help you,add a new panel.Right click that panel and select **Add to Panel**

[image]

From the drop down list select **Menu Bar** and click add..It will bring the Application Menu.There is also a [Alternative for Gnome Panel Menu Bar](http://maketecheasier.com/4-great-alternatives-to-gnome-menu-bar/2010/06/08)

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary here.